# Drawing directions from google map api

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to draw a direction line from marker to another. I already turned on directions in google map api. I got this function in here (SO). I understand what its doing but I can not get it to work. The `routes array` returns empty. I have tried multiple points for tests. Here is the functions:

```
func drawPath2(origin: CLLocationCoordinate2D, destination: CLLocationCoordinate2D)
{

let origin = "\(origin.latitude),\(origin.longitude)"
    let destination = "\(destination.latitude),\(destination.longitude)"
    let apiKey = "Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

    guard let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(origin)&destination=\(destination)&key=AIzaSyAOhiBw8mSPBmmAJQ_fjM79x7ruvMxFmxQ") else {return}

    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
        print(response.request)  // original URL request
        print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
        print(response.data)     // server data
        print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

        let json = try! JSON(data: response.data!)
        let routes = json["routes"].arrayValue

        //remove this after test
        print(routes.count)

        for route in routes
        {
            let routeOverviewPolyline = route["overview_polyline"].dictionary
            let points = routeOverviewPolyline?["points"]?.stringValue
            let path = GMSMutablePath.init(fromEncodedPath: points!)
            let polyline = GMSPolyline.init(path: path)
            polyline.map = self.mapView
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the print() results:

`Optional(https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=49.18705,-123.107261&destination=49.1844,-123.1052&mode=driving&key=AIzaSyAOhiBw8mSPBmmAJQ_fjM79x7ruvMxFmxQ)
Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x6000024c5ba0> { URL: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=49.18705,-123.107261&destination=49.1844,-123.1052&mode=driving&key=AIzaSyAOhiBw8mSPBmmAJQ_fjM79x7ruvMxFmxQ } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
    "Cache-Control" =     (
        "no-cache, must-revalidate"
    );
    "Content-Encoding" =     (
        gzip
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        130
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Mon, 10 Dec 2018 22:28:52 GMT"
    );
    Expires =     (
        "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
    );
    Pragma =     (
        "no-cache"
    );
    Server =     (
        mafe
    );
    Vary =     (
        "Accept-Language"
    );
    "alt-svc" =     (
        "quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"44,43,39,35\""
    );
    "x-frame-options" =     (
        SAMEORIGIN
    );
    "x-xss-protection" =     (
        "1; mode=block"
    );
} })
Optional(129 bytes)
SUCCESS
0`

I do not see `data` in there at all. I think something is wrong with URL or request. Please help me sirs and madams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect, your `api key` is not authorized to use this service. You can verify by printing `json`

```
print(json)
```

You should see this in `response` where the `routes` array is empty,

```
{
    "error_message" = "This API project is not authorized to use this API.";
    routes =     (
    );
    status = "REQUEST_DENIED";
}
```

Comment: yeah, this was the problem.

Answer (score -3):

Go to [Google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library?project=) and create a new project and enable Direction API. [API Libary](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library?project=)
And Place your API Key in your `url` 
See this [Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro) It helps you for sample API and Response for Google Direction API.